# Vuejs Loop trough all children and execute a function for each iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I recently started to work with Vue.js, I'm trying to make something super simple tho on vue everything seems super complicated when doing simple things, especially when you don't have 5 years of vue behind you.

So basically, Imagine I have this component:

```html
<template>
    <section class="stuff">
     <div class="hello pop1">div content</div>
        <ul>
            <li class="hello pop2"> stuff </li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </section>
</template>
```

I want to loop trough all childs of `stuff` so I can add remove one of their class with a timeout between each iteration.

I used to do it like that with jQuery:

```js
        $(".stuff").find("*").each(function(i){ 
            setTimeout ( function(){ 
                $("stuff").find(".pop" + i ).removeClass("hello"); 
            },i * 100);
        });
```

(This is an example so the fact that I manually typed is normal)

What's the easiest way to reproduce that in Vue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting a staggered animation by removing classes, you might find Vue's [TransitionGroup](https://Https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition-group.html) helpful! Here's a general example:

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <transition-group tag="ul" name="slide-in" :style="{ '--total': list.length }">
    <li v-for="l,i in list" key="i" :style="{'--i': i}" v-if="showItems && i < 10">Item {{ l }}</li>
  </transition-group>
</div>
```

CSS (fancy-dancy slide-in animation)

```
.slide-in {
  
  &-move {
    transition: opacity .5s linear, transform .5s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  &-leave-active {
    transition: opacity .4s linear, transform .4s cubic-bezier(.5,0,.7,.4); //cubic-bezier(.7,0,.7,1); 
    transition-delay: calc( 0.1s * (var(--total) - var(--i)) );
  }
  
  &-enter-active { 
    transition: opacity .5s linear, transform .5s cubic-bezier(.2,.5,.1,1);
    transition-delay: calc( 0.1s * var(--i) );
  }

  &-enter, 
  &-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  &-enter { transform: translateX(-1em); }
  &-leave-to { transform: translateX(1em); }

}
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      showItems: false,
      list: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    }

  },
  mounted(){
    this.$nextTick(()=>{ this.showItems=true });
  }
});
```

[Here's a codepen of all that](https://codepen.io/TravisFranklin/pen/YzEROoJ).

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer indeed it looks helpful, but in your example you still use the vfor to generate the items, I will have some case where it will be like that so I'll be able to use that but in the case where the content is not generated like this (like in my example) can I still use this ?

Comment: No problemo! Yeah! Just make sure each element inside TransitionGroup has a unique `key` param!

Comment: Welp I'm trying to adapt that solution for elements that aren't in a list but I just can't what I did is wrap the thing I want to animate in the `transition-group` give it a name and use your css (with the same slide-in name), I tried using a v-for="stuff in this" but it does't work as well, I can edit my question with the code I tried using your example

Comment: Yeah dude, I'll try to help if I can!